# Maximize/Minimize HTML Table by <th> USing JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a huge table with multiple table headers.  I want to be able to maximize or minimize these headers using JQuery (or whatever works).
Here is an example table:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically in this example, I would like two minimize/maximize buttons that interact apart from each other (if I hit one, the other is unchanged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("p").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Basically this script above targets the `id="hide"`

so when you click on the id element "hide" it starts up the Jquery function and hides the `<p>` element.

Then the same way targets `id="show"`

Just get a good read on it, it's quite simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an id to the table like below

```
<table id="tb1">
```

Then you can use jQuery to hide the table on button click

```
$("button#minimize").click(function(){
   $("div#tb1").hide();
})
```

Similarly you can show the table on maximize button click. Buttons should have the id `maximize` and `minimize`.